# NSViewController's view size is not the same as the window's, I print the size in the viewDidLoad method and get (480.0, 270.0)

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nswindow, core-text

NSViewController's view size is not the same as the window's, I print the size in the viewDidLoad method and get (480.0, 270.0)

I'm not very familiar with appkit and I find that no matter how I resize the window and then re-run it, it prints (480.0, 270.0) every time, but the window size stays the same length and width as last time. I noticed that these two values were set in the storyboard, but I needed real values to calculate the layout of the text, and I tried window's proxy method, but that was too late. By that time the view had already been rendered and calculated

After various attempts it didn't work

Comment: Do you recalculate when the user resizes the window?

Comment: @Willeke Yes I will recalculate, now I roughly reload the view once on app startup, at callback, to guarantee correct typography, but it's weird.

Comment: How about recalculating when the view resizes?